# Codility Test : Square Number

Tags: python

I had a Codility Test, and the question asked me to create a code that listed numbers 1-1000, but at every square number, the program prints
"POWER" instead of the square number. It should look like this:

```
POWER
2
3
POWER
5
6
7
8
POWER
10
```

And so on...
I've been trying to solve this, but I can't think of any correct solutions, any help would be much appreciated.

```
for n in range(1,11):
    print(n)
    if n == n**2:
        print("POWER")
    elif n==22:
        print("POWER")
    elif n==3**2:
        print("POWER")
```

This is the only thing I could think of, but I don't know how I could create a loop for this 1000 times, also the output didn't come out as I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The important things you're missing are the `math.sqrt` and `round` functions, which make it very easy to figure out if a number is a perfect square (just check whether the `sqrt` of the number is `round`):

```
import math

for n in range(1,1001):
    s = math.sqrt(n)
    if s == round(s):
        print("POWER")
    else:
        print(n)
```

If you weren't allowed to use those functions, another option (which would save you from having to do a guess-and-test iteration for each number) would be to build a set of square numbers within the range you care about and test each `n` for membership in that set:

```
squares = {n ** 2 for n in range(1, 32)}
for n in range(1,1001):
    if n in squares:
        print("POWER")
    else:
        print(n)
```

Comment: You are a star, this worked! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My solution is: calculate sqrt of number, check if it is a whole number using built-in method `is_integer()` on float object:

```
import math
for i in range(1000):
    if math.sqrt(i).is_integer():
        print("POWER")
    else:
        print(i)
```